# Can I call host process function with c string in gdb?

Tags: python-2.7, memory, gdb

`PyString_InternFromString` is a c function with the following declaration.

```
PyObject *PyString_InternFromString(const char *cp)
```

I called this function in gdb with the following commands and outputs.

```
(gdb) p (char *) malloc(10)
$8 = 0xcfd020 "\210\066▒\364\177"
(gdb) call strcpy(0xcfd020, "nihao")
$9 = 13619232
(gdb) p PyString_InternFromString
$10 = {PyObject *(const char *)} 0x419158 <PyString_InternFromString>
(gdb) break PyObject_Malloc
Breakpoint 1 at 0x418004: PyObject_Malloc. (17 locations)
(gdb) p 0xcfd020
$11 = 13619232
(gdb) p (const char*)0xcfd020
$12 = 0xcfd020 "nihao"
(gdb)  p ((PyObject * (*)(const char *))0x419158)((const char *)0xcfd020)
Breakpoint 1, PyString_InternFromString (cp=0x64 <error: Cannot access    memory at address 0x64>) at ../Objects/stringobject.c:4783
4783    ../Objects/stringobject.c: No such file or directory.
The program being debugged stopped while in a function called from GDB.
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(PyString_InternFromString) will be abandoned.
 When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
(gdb) bt
#0  PyString_InternFromString (cp=0x64 <error: Cannot access memory at    address 0x64>) at ../Objects/stringobject.c:4783
#1  0x00007ff489a1a0c0 in ?? ()
#2  0x7b752ef9cf7f0a00 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007ff489b1b050 in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000000000065 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
PyObject_Malloc (nbytes=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/obmalloc.c:882
882     ../Objects/obmalloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  PyObject_Malloc (nbytes=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/obmalloc.c:882
#1  PyString_FromString (str=0x64 <error: Cannot access memory at address     0x64>) at ../Objects/stringobject.c:143
#2  PyString_InternFromString (cp=0x64 <error: Cannot access memory at   address 0x64>) at ../Objects/stringobject.c:4783
#3  0x00007ff489a1a0c0 in ?? ()
#4  0x7b752ef9cf7f0a00 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007ff489b1b050 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000000000065 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) info locals
bp = <optimized out>
pool = 0x7ff489a0a370
next = <optimized out>
size = 9607536
(gdb) info args
nbytes = <optimized out>
(gdb) f 1
#1  PyString_FromString (str=0x64 <error: Cannot access memory at address   0x64>) at ../Objects/stringobject.c:143
143     ../Objects/stringobject.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) info locals
size = 100
op = <optimized out>
(gdb) info args
str = 0x64 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x64>
(gdb)  p ((PyObject * (*)(const char *))0x419158)(&((const char *)0xcfd020))
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
(gdb) call strlen("nihaobuhoa")
$13 = 10
```

I failed to call the function with **`Segmentation fault`**. We can learn that **`Cannot access memory at address 0x64`** cause the fault from the output. This really confused me, what I gave to `PyString_InternFromString` was a `const char *` string at address `0xcfd020`, but change to `0x64` in the function. 
Any one know why this happened?

Comment: I think a lot of the missing and confusing info you're seeing from gdb is because you're running an optimized version of the python interpreter. If you can get a "debug build" of python (on Ubuntu, this is the package `python2.7-dbg`), you'll find that you won't get the `optimized out` messages.

Comment: I have tried python debug version but no same error occured. @MarkPlotnick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because gdb read wrong address of PyString_InternFromString from symbol table. I dumped python symbol table into a plain text file and found that the real address of PyString_InternFromString is different from the address printed from gdb.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the way you call your function hides too many things to GDB.

Instead of invoking the casted pointer to function `PyString_InternFromString()`, Why don't you simply call it directly? You can also use a C string when calling a function, GDB automatically calls `malloc()` for you to create the string.

```
(gdb) # reach a point where every initializations of your call (and
subcalls) are done. For example, main.  
(gdb) b main  
(gdb) run  
(gdb) p /x PyString_InternFromString("nihao")
```

Notes:

1. This call implicitly depends on prior initialization of everything it requires, i.e., global objects directly or indirectly used. If this is the case, you should first break and perform this call after such initializations.
2. Calling functions from GDB at least requires the C runtime to be first initialized for the same reasons stated in point 1. So you should perform your calls when you have reached the `main()` function.
3. It is possible to debug a function called through GDB (as stated by the error message `../Objects/stringobject.c: No such file or directory.`). Download it and [specify the directory to GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html), you should then be able to debug it (debug informations may be separate if this is a library from you OS distribution)